# Left side menus/controls not showing in new top bar

Tags: bug, top-bar

On my Linux box at home, using Firefox, the top bar works great, and I'm loving it. On my Windows box at work, using Firefox, it worked well up until a few days ago, at which point it still *works*, but has some display problems. This is what it looks like:

[image: No menus on left side]

Oddly enough, I can still expand the menus:

[image: Can still expand community menu]

---

[image: Can still expand inbox]

---

[image: Can still expand achievements]

I cleared my browser cache, but that did not fix it. I am going to take my work laptop home to see whether it is some sort of work firewall issue, and will report back.

### Update

- I have the problem even when I am not connected to my work VPN.
- The bar looks fine in Chrome on the same computer.
- I can reach SStatic content delivery network test image in the errant browser.

Comment: Are you running into any other issues with using the sites? Does anything turn up in the dev console? How about other browsers? Are you able to reach cdn.sstatic.net? Specifically, can you retrieve http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.png?

Comment: Adblock? There have been five million bug reports about ABP killing those images. (Darn it @ShadowWizard, beat me by three seconds...)

Comment: @AnnaLear AdBlocker. Stack Exchange sites are one big advertisement. (Stack Overflow is fine, they added an exception :-))

Comment: @michaelb958 feel free to add your close vote.

Comment: That seems like an odd reason to close my question---if I had known the problem was AdBlock Plus, I would have fixed it myself instead of asking the question. Are you confusing question and answer here?

Comment: @Kazark closed as *duplicate*. No point reporting same bug more than once. (which in this case isn't a bug, at least not on SE side)

Comment: Oh, I see. The original title and the question body are more like mine. The changed title oddly enough expresses the answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, I understand. It's just an odd scenario since if I had been able to find that question, all I would have needed to see what the title in order to not ask mine. In other words, I had no way of finding the question. Oh well; glad to have an answer.

Comment: Well, the tags were off, fixed them to reflect it's an issue with the design of top bar. Hopefully it will make it easier for others to find in the future.